# Split dates by other dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table `rate` with the following structure (approximate):

```
CREATE TABLE `rate` (
    `id`       int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `from`     date NOT NULL,
    `to`       date NOT NULL
)
```

And an (approximately) identical table `stop_sale`:

```
CREATE TABLE `stop_sale` (
    `id`       int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `from`     date NOT NULL,
    `to`       date NOT NULL
)
```

Considering that, for each one, their *time interval* is the range of days they cover between their respective `from` and `to` fields:

I want to query these tables together in such a way that the time intervals do not overlap, but instead adjust so that `stop_sale` takes priority.

### Example

`rates`

```
| id | from         | to           |
| 1  | "2018-01-05" | "2018-01-31" |
| 2  | "2018-02-01" | "2018-02-15" |
```

`stop_sale`

```
| id | from         | to           |
| 1  | "2018-01-11" | "2018-01-20" |
| 2  | "2018-02-01" | "2018-02-10" |
```

*Desired Result*

```
| rate_id | from         | to           |
| 1       | "2018-01-05" | "2018-01-10" |
| 0       | "2018-01-11" | "2018-01-20" |
| 1       | "2018-01-21" | "2018-01-31" |
| 0       | "2018-02-01" | "2018-02-10" |
| 2       | "2018-02-11" | "2018-02-15" |
```

Notice how `rate` with `id=1` gets split into two records based on the time interval of `stop_rate` with `id=1` (Note: `id`s are not important, just the time intervals).

In other words, `stop_sale` time intervals perform a subtraction operation upon the time intervals of `rate`, and are also painted with the final result set.

- Is this possible with SQL? And MySQL?
- If so, how optimal a query is it? Is it better to handle this operation in PHP?

Comment: Can you please explain more your Desired Result ??

Comment: I added some more information, and removed data that I considered irrelevant after a second revision. I hope the changes are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do this with just a SQL query. This could be solved iteratively within a stored function, however there is no clean option to return the data. The best being returning a delimited string of the data.

An alternative is to build a store procedure that populates a table of the result data periodically and have php query against that. The basic logic would be:

pass in starting data value - starting date.

create a temp table with query:

```
    select * from rates
    where from >= starting_date
    union
    select * from stop_sale
    where from >= starting_date
    order by from asc
```

- Iterated through temp table.

  - get first 'from' value.
  - get next greater 'to' value
  - look for 'from' value < current 'to' value and > current 'from' value but != 'from' values already in the results table being populated

    - if found insert current 'from' value and 'to' value -1day into results table being populated
    - else insert current 'from' value and 'to' value into results table being populated

This basic logic could be done in php, although it may be more complicated since you would need to build an array of the rows returned from the above temp table query, run the logic on it, and build out an array of results. This would be less efficient than running the stored procedure as once the stored procedure is run you would only need to run it again on the data newer than that run. Hence the starting_data parameter.